# Returning two values from Function in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a function in VBA which will calculate two values.Is there any way that i can get those two values returned from the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA You can return more values by two ways: return an array or use ByRef declaration, see this:

```
    'return as array
    Function ReturnTwoValues(x As Long) As Long()
        Dim ret(1) As Long
        ret(0) = x
        ret(1) = x * 2
        ReturnTwoValues = ret
    End Function

    'return parameters declared as ByRef
    Sub ReturnTwoPars(x As Long, ByRef y1 As Long, ByRef y2 As Long)
        y1 = x
        y2 = x * 2
    End Sub


    Sub Test()
        'return an array
        Dim ar() As Long
        ar = ReturnTwoValues(2) 'variable must be the same type as function
        Debug.Print ar(0), ar(1)

        'use ByRef
        Dim y1 As Long
        Dim y2 As Long
        ReturnTwoPars 2, y1, y2
        Debug.Print y1, y2

    End Sub
```

Comment: `Sub multireturn()
Dim a(10) As Long
x = 7
a = twovalue(x)

MsgBox "value is " & a(0) & " New value is " & a(1)
End Sub
Function twovalue(x) As Long()
Dim b(10) As Long
b(0) = x
b(1) = x * 10
twovalue = b
End Function`

I am getting compile error "Cant assign array".. Am i missing anything

Comment: In your example: function _twovalue_ is type _Long()_, however array a(10) is type _Long(10)_. Change definition of array "a" this way: 'Dim a() As Long'

Comment: @ roman pliske : I declared like this `Dim a() as long ` and i have used msgbox to print the value... i am getting out of context error at this statement ` MsgBox "Value is " & a(1)` pointing to ` a(1) `

Comment: Are you sure, that the returned array in your function is declared as dim(1)? See example above - in _Sub Test_ is declared array without elements; in _Function ReturnTwoValues_ is declared with two elements and then is returned. After calling you can access both elements - ar(0), ar(1), not before calling.

Comment: @ Roman Pliske : Sorry, mistake is mine... I have declared returned array in the function as dynamic one...

Comment: OK. If you are satisfied with my answer, mark it as answer please.