# excel vba - returns two value, passing one input parameter

Tags: excel, vba, function

This is the case: 
I need to have two values back from a function: this function needs an input parameter to works.

strTitleName: input parameter
sName: output paramter
sScope: output paramter

```
Function getScenarioName(strTitleName As String, sName As String, sScope As String)
    activateSheet ("Test Scenarios")
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = strTitleName & "*"
    Set rng1 = Range("B:B").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
     'getScenarioName = rng1.Offset(0, 0)
     sName = rng1.Address
     sScope = rng1.Offset(1, 1).Address
    Debug.Print "sName=" & sName
    Debug.Print "sScope=" & sScope
End If
```

How can I getout in a subroutine the values of sName and sScope?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning two values from Function in Word VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857214/returning-two-values-from-function-in-word-vba)

Comment: Also, here's the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-arrays) on arrays.

Comment: How about returning "rng1" and building both results outside your function?

Comment: sorry but is not a duplicate since my two parameters sName and sScope are not input, but output

Comment: @Asger thanks, it's a good idea! I'll try this one!

Comment: You either pass the value using ByRef or use a collection to return multiple values.  I prefer a collection to an array as there is then no restriction to the type of  the variables that you can pass back.  Most likely you will prefer the ByRef approach.

Comment: @Asger that's a semi-good idea (breaks the abstraction and leaks implementation details into the caller) *in this situation* - but doing that won't teach OP anything about `ByRef` vs `ByVal`, which is clearly the concept at play here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept at play here is `ByRef` vs`ByVal` parameters.

In VBA parameters are passed *by reference* unless specified otherwise, which is... an unfortunate default: in most other languages, parameters are passed *by value*.

99% of the time, you don't need to pass anything `ByRef`, so `ByVal` is perfect, and should be specified explicitly... 99% of the time.

Passing parameters `ByRef` is useful for cases like this, when you need to return two or more values and returning an instance of a class encapsulating the return values would be overkill.

Keep in mind that a `Function` procedure always returns a value, even if you don't declare a return type. If you fail to declare a return type, and never assign a return value, the function will return `Variant/Empty`, which makes for a rather confusing and non-idiomatic API.

Here are a couple options:

#### ByRef return parameters

Say your signature looked like this:

```
Public Function GetScenarioName(ByVal title As String, ByRef outName As String, ByRef outScope As String) As Boolean
```

Now you can return `True` when the function succeeds, `False` when it doesn't (say, if `rng1` happens to be `Nothing`), and then assign the `outName` and `outScope` parameters.

Because they're passed *by reference*, the calling code gets to see the new values - so the caller would look like this:

```
Dim scenarioTitle As String
scenarioTitle = "title"

Dim scenarioName As String, scenarioScope As String
If GetScenarioName(scenarioTitle, scenarioName, scenarioScope) Then
    Debug.Print scenarioName, scenarioScope
Else
    Debug.Print "No scenario was found for title '" & scenarioTitle & "'."
End If
```

What happens is that *the function receives a copy* of the `scenarioTitle` variable - that copy is essentially a variable that's local to the function: if you re-assign it in the body of the function, the caller doesn't get to see the updated value, the original argument remains unaffected (and this is why `ByVal` is the safest way to pass parameters).

But the function also receives a *reference* to the `scenarioName` and `scenarioScope` variables - and when it assigns to its `outName` and `outScope` parameters, the value held by that reference is updated accordingly - and the caller gets to see the updated values.

#### User-Defined Type

Still leveraging `ByRef` return values, it can sometimes be a good idea to encapsulate members in a cohesive unit: VBA lets you create user-defined types, for the simple cases where you just need to toss a bunch of values around:

```
Public Type TScenario
    Title As String
    Name As String
    Scope As String
    '...
End Type
```

```
Public Function GetScenarioInfo(ByRef info As TScenario) As Boolean
```

Now this function would work similarly, except now you no longer need to change its signature whenever you want to add a parameter: simply add the new member to `TScenario` and you're good to go!

The calling code would be doing this:

```
Dim result As TScenario
result.Tite = "title"
If GetScenarioInfo(result) Then
    Debug.Print result.Name, result.Scope
Else
    Debug.Print "No scenario was found for title '" & result.Title & "'."
End If
```

Alternatively, you could have a full-fledged class module to encapsulate the `ScenarioInfo` - in which case...

#### Full-Blown OOP

Encapsulating everything you need in its own class module gives you the most flexibility: now your function can return an object reference!

```
Public Function GetScenarioName(ByVal title As String) As ScenrioInfo
```

Now the function can return `Nothing` if no scenario is found, and there's no need for any parameters other than the *input* one:

```
Dim scenarioTitle As String
scenarioTitle = "title"

Dim result As ScenarioInfo
Set result = GetScenarioInfo(scenarioTitle)
If Not result Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print result.Name, result.Scope
Else
    Debug.Print "No scenario was found for title '" & scenarioTitle & "'."
End If
```

This is IMO the cleanest approach, but does require a bit of boilerplate - namely, the `ScenarioInfo` class module. The simplest possible implementation would simply expose read/write public fields:

```
Option Explicit
Public Name As String
Public Scope As String
```

More elaborate implementations could involve an `IScenarioInfo` interface that only exposes `Property Get` members, the `ScenarioInfo` class that `Implements IScenarioInfo`, a `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute (that's... hidden... and much easier to handle with the [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) VBIDE add-in) with a public *factory method* that lets you parameterize the object's creation - turning the function into something like this:

```
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    Set GetScenarioInfo = ScenarioInfo.Create(rng1.Address, rng1.Offset(1,1).Address)
End If
```

If that's an approach you find interesting, you can read up about it on the [Rubberduck News](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/04/24/factories-parameterized-object-initialization/) blog, which I maintain.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. it's very easy and clear. I choose solution 1 and it works perfectly! thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array inside the function to store both values. Then, return the array.

For example:

```
'If strTitleName is your only argument, then:
Function getScenarioName(strTitleName As String) As Variant

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim result(1) As String

    activateSheet ("Test Scenarios")

    Set rng1 = Range("B:B").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    strSearch = strTitleName & "*"

    result(0) = ""
    result(1) = ""

    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then

        sName = rng1.Address
        sScope = rng1.Offset(1, 1).Address

        Debug.Print "sName=" & sName
        Debug.Print "sScope=" & sScope

        result(0) = "sName=" & sName
        result(1) = "sScope=" & sScope

    End If

    getScenarioName = result

End Function
```

Comment: how can I retrieve the values in the sub?

Comment: For example:

`myVariable = getScenarioName(strTitleName, sName, sScope)

So, myVariable(0) will store the value of 'sName' and myVariable(1) the value of 'sScope'`

Comment: I got this Compile error:

ByRef argument type mismatch

Comment: That error is referring to a argument type mismatch. Check the values you're passing.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Freeflow's suggestion of the collection, here's your updated code:

```
Function getScenarioName(strTitleName As String, sName As String, sScope As String) as Collection
    activateSheet ("Test Scenarios")
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = strTitleName & "*"
    Set rng1 = Range("B:B").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        'getScenarioName = rng1.Offset(0, 0)
        sName = rng1.Address
        sScope = rng1.Offset(1, 1).Address

        dim colToReturn as Collection
        set colToReturn = New Collection
        colToReturn.Add sName
        colToReturn.Add sScope

        Set getScenarioName = colToReturn

    End If
End Function
```